# Is there a way to input a list into a function which has *args as its argument in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, args

Currently, I'm working on a problem on CodeWars named "Training on Calculating with Functions" using Python 3.6. The way that this problem works is, for example, if `seven(times(five()))` is called, then the function should return 35. Here is a snippet from my code:

```
def nine(arr):  # your code here
    if arr is None:
        return 9
    return operator(arr[0], 9, arr[1])


def plus(num):  # your code here
    return ["+", num]


def operator(op, n1, n2):
    switcher = {
        "+": n1 + n2,
        "-": n1 - n2,
        "*": n1 * n2,
        "/": n1 / n2
    }

    return switcher.get(op, "Invalid")
```

The full code is on this link (with -> top and without -> bottom args): [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/zaqujifito.py)

My logic here (originally) was to use `*args` as the argument, and if `args` was `None` then the function would return its own value (`five() => 5`), this value would then be passed into one of the 'operator' functions, which would return a list of its own operator (i.e. +, -, /, *) and the number passed into it. Then, in the outermost function, you would pass in the array from the 'operator' function, since `args` was not `None`, you would take the first item in the `args` tuple (the returned value from the 'operator' function which was passed in), then you would access that lists' first and second values, the rest is pretty self-explanatory.

However, when I attempted to run this, I would get the error `index beyond tuple range` (ref: line 95 on Hastebin). As a result, I switched to a new logic where I would explicitly add the argument to. the function, but (obviously), when run, there was an error that no argument was passed into the function (innermost function --> `five()` in `seven(times(five()))`).

I would like to know if there are any ways I can fix my existing code, but any alternate solutions are more than welcome.

Additionally, here is a link to the kata: [Codewars Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/525f3eda17c7cd9f9e000b39/train/python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a default value to the argument. If no argument is passed, the default value will be used instead. Since you check for `None`, you can use `None` as the default value.

```py
def nine(arr=None):
    if arr is None:
        return 9
    else:
        return operator(arr[0], 9, arr[1])

def five(arr=None):
    if arr is None:
        return 5
    else:
        return operator(arr[0], 5, arr[1])

def plus(num):  # your code here
    return ["+", num]

def operator(op, n1, n2):
    switcher = {
        "+": n1 + n2,
        "-": n1 - n2,
        "*": n1 * n2,
        "/": n1 / n2
    }
    return switcher.get(op, "Invalid")

print(nine(plus(five()))
# 14
```

### Issue with your `operator` function: python `dict` is non-lazy

Note that python `dict` are not lazy. This means that when you define `switcher` the way you do, it immediately performs the four calculations `n1 + n2, n1 - n2, n1 * n2, n1 / n2`. This is a problem, especially since the division `n1 / n2` will fail with exception `ZeroDivisionError` if `n2` is `0`.

One solution is to use a dict of functions instead of a dict of numbers:

```py
def operator(op, n1, n2):
    switcher = {
        "+": lambda x,y: x+y,
        "-": lambda x,y: x-y,
        "*": lambda x,y: x*y,
        "/": lambda x,y: x/y,
    }
    return switcher[op](n1, n2)
```

Note that those four functions are already defined in the python module `operator` and are called `add`, `sub`, `mul`, `floordiv` (or `truediv`). [Refer to the documentation on module `operator`.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) For instance, `operator.add(x,y)` is synonymous for `x+y`. But you can write fun things like `return operator.add`, whereas you can't write `return (+)` in python.

Since this module is already called `operator`, you should probably find another name for your `operator` function.

```py
import operator

def nine(arr=None):
    if arr is None:
        return 9
    else:
        return exec_op(arr[0], 9, arr[1])

def plus(num):  # your code here
    return ["+", num]

def exec_op(op, n1, n2):
  switcher = {
        "+": operator.add,
        "-": operator.sub,
        "*": operator.mul,
        "/": operator.floordiv
    }
  return switcher[op](n1, n2)

print(nine(plus(nine())))
# 18
```

### The other way: make `plus` return a function

Here is another way, which doesn't store the operations as lists of strings and numbers, and does not require an extra function `operator`/`exec_op` to evaluate the operation.

We are going to make `plus(y)` literally return the function `? + y`.

```py
def plus(y):
  return lambda x: x+y

def nine(op=None):
  if op is None:
    return 9
  else:
    return op(9)

print(nine(plus(nine())))
# 18
```

We can simplify this further by using a function instead of `None` as the default argument for `nine`:

```py
identity = lambda x: x

def plus(y):
  return lambda x: x+y

def nine(op=identity):
  return op(9)

print(nine(plus(nine())))
# 18
```

Comment: I'd use a different name for `id`, you shouldn't shadow builtins.

Comment: @Jasmijn Thanks! I renamed it to `identity`. I wasn't aware of that builtin.