# python append args to function call

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def one(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return 1

    return args


def plus(*args):
    first_number = args[1]
    second_number = args[0]
    sum = first_number + second_number 
    return sum


def two(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return 2
    
    return args


print(one(plus(two())))
```

the question is to do calculations by using functions and it contains 3 parts first number, operation, and the second number and the goal is to do the operation (second part) on those two numbers (first part and third part) for example `one(plus(two()))` should return 3

now here is the part I don't know how to do, `plus()` function is called with one argument `two()` `one(plus(two()))` I want to add a second argument the initial number (first number) to the function so `plus()` function is now called with two `args` like this `plus(two(), 1)`.

Now `plus(two())` is `args[0]` inside `one()` function how can I append `1` to that `args[0]` so that the function be called like this `plus(two(), 1)` to access it inside `plus()` and `first_number = args[1]` becomes valid

Comment: Why are you using `*args` even though you allow only one variation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to input a list into a function which has \*args as its argument in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785738/is-there-a-way-to-input-a-list-into-a-function-which-has-args-as-its-argument-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below implements a similar syntax to the example, but with slightly different argument structure. I think this way the logic is clearer.

The point is that I define `plus` as a partial function so that it "absorb" two to form a function that works as "add_two".

```py
def plus(number):
  def _plus(x):
    return x + number
  return _plus

def one(op=None):  
  if op is None:
    return 1  
  return op(1)

def two(op=None):
  if op is None:
    return 2
  return op(2)

one(plus(two()))
# 3
```

Comment: Cool! I tried adding a `mult` method similar to `plus` and that too works! `two(mult(one(plus(two()))))` gives 6!

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to have `plus` return a function that will be called afterward by `one` or `two`:

```
def one(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return 1
    elif len(args) == 1:
        fn = args[0]
        return fn(1)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid number of arguments")

def two(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return 2
    elif len(args) == 1:
        fn = args[0]
        return fn(2)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid number of arguments")


def plus(second_number):
    def adder(first_number):
        return first_number + second_number
    return adder
```

Now:

```
>>> one(plus(two()))
3
>>> one(plus(one()))
2
>>> two(plus(one()))
3
>>> two(plus(two()))
4
```

And to simplify and DRY it:

```
def make_number(n):
    def number_fn(fn=None):
        if fn:
            return fn(n)
        else:
            return n
    return number_fn

def make_operator(operator):
    def operator_wrapper(second_number):
        def partial(first_number):
            return operator(first_number, second_number)
        return partial
    return operator_wrapper

one = make_number(1)
two = make_number(2)

plus = make_operator(lambda a, b: a + b)
minus = make_operator(lambda a, b: a - b)
```

```
>>> two(minus(one()))
1
```

Comment: This syntax hurts my eyes